# What kind of relationship should "made of" and "made from" belong to in UML?

Tags: uml, relationship

Please Look at the following example:
1) The chairs are made of wood .
2) Paper is made from trees .
3) Biogas is produced by the fermentation of waste.
4) Asphalt is produced through the refining of petroleum.
Should these be Composition or Dependency?

Comment: So to put it another way, What is the relationship between an object and the material it is made of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### In general

You can exclude UML composition:  composition implies an exclusive ownership.  But chairs are not the only products made of wood.

Dependency is either too much  (once the biogas is made, there is no dependency to waste anymore) or not enough (the wood of the chair is part of the chair; it's a stronger relationship than a need-to-know-about).

Moreover it is not clear if you want the Chair to be a class on its own or an instance of a class product.

### Specific cases

"***Made of***" expresses a relationship with parts that make a product.  A typical pattern here is the [bill of material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_of_materials).  The relation is a simple association.  Some people tend to use UML aggregation, but UML specifications do not define precisely the semantics, so leave it out to avoid ambiguity.

Here a (very simplified) diagram:

[image]

"***Made from***" expresses a transformation process, where some of the original products disappear in the process and others are created.  Paper is made from cellulose which is extracted from trees.  But the original tree is not in the sheet of paper.

Typically in process industries, like chemicals, this is represented by a "recipe",  which is a sequence of inputs (waste) and operation to obtain products (biogas) and co-products (fermented residual waste). In other industries, this is represented by a "routing" that is a sequence of operations performed on a BOM (in this case, the BOM would not only contain components as previously shown, but also raw products that are transformed by the operations in the routing).

I will not show a diagram because this is quickly very complex, but again, it'll use simple associations.

In the end,  "made of" and "made from"  would both be represented in UML with associations.  But only the semantic that you attach to it will change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that any "made of" is represented by some static relation. To make a wooden chair it just `Depend`s on wood. There is no other relation here because you have some complicated process to turn wood into a chair. Or a tree into paper. Or anything else of your choices. In order to describe the relation you would need to describe the process. This is possible using activities. You could as well descibe physical components with UML. But that would take us too far apart from your question...

You might search for answers on composition here. But even these can be looked at controversial. Modeling reality yields a model. Which is not reality.

Answer (score 0):

Your question highlights the difference between an ontology and an information model or application design. For example, in a conceptual ontology (which accounts for necessary and possible situations in the world rather than for data formats of observations and measurements), every person has a mother. In a particular database or application, that knowledge is usually irrelevant. What stuff is made of and how it is produced belongs more to a conceptual ontology, for which UML is not quite expressive enough. This is why languages such as First Order Logic (FOL) and OWL are used instead, and why some tools (such as my company’s) plug holes in UML. (One example of a hole in UML is the inability to express *exactly* the intersection of two classes.)